# TypeError: Request url must be str or unicode, got list:

Tags: python, web, scrapy

I am trying to extract and save the image but everytime I run spider I am getting this error , i have defined following functions in items.py

```
import scrapy   
from ..items import HamrobazarItem


class CarsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'cars'
    start_urls = ['https://hamrobazaar.com/c48-automobiles-cars']

    def parse(self, response):
        items= HamrobazarItem()
        img_urls=list()
        img_urls.append(response.css('center img::attr(src)').extract())
        items['image_urls']=img_urls

        yield items
```

```
import scrapy

class HamrobazarItem(scrapy.Item):
    images=scrapy.Field()
    image_urls=scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

Comment: The code snippet seems wrongly formatted. I never used scrapy, are you sure in `yield items`? It yields list, not item of the list, maybe this is an error?

Comment: I used return as well. But it didnt work

Comment: I see here - https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html that `parse()` should return not list of URLs (to be parsed), but to yield `Request` objects: `yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't run your spider but it seems that the problem is yielding list of lists. `response.css('center img::attr(src)').extract()` is a list and `img_urls.append(response.css('center img::attr(src)').extract())` is a list of list so changing it to `img_urls = response.css('center img::attr(src)').extract()` may solve your problem.

Comment: Initially there was ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True in settings.py file I modified it to ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False and that worked for me

Comment: Are you able to get the image but you are unable to store it ?